# AngularFire Tic Tac Toe Game

Tags: javascript, game, angular.js, api, promise

I am building a Tic Tac Toe game with AngularJS and making it online playable with AngularFire.  The Tic Tac Toe logic is all there so this question concerns Angularfire a little bit more. I want to be able to match a user with an opponent as well as delete inactive games.

I have done my homework and at this point I want to get the smell out of my code.  Since I am handling asynchronous requests, I built a factory that returns a promise.

```
app.factory("GameCreator", ["$q","$firebase",function($q, $firebase){
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    var ref = new Firebase("https://myfirebase.firebaseio.com/");
    $firebase(ref).$on("loaded",function(value){
        var games = $firebase(ref);
        var IDs = games.$getIndex();
        var initGame = function(n){
            games.$add({
                //the board's state and turns, shared by all users
                board:[['','',''],['','',''],['','','']],
                xTurn:true,
                turns:0,
                playerone:{piece:'x', ready:false,won:false},
                playertwo:{piece:'o',ready:false,won:false},
                //helpers to sync and assign player
                xIsAvailable:false,
                oIsAvailable:true
            });
            //my opponent did something.  His/her actions need to appear on my screen.
            games.$on("change",function(){  
                deferred.resolve( games.$child(games.$getIndex()[n]) );
            });
        };
        var n = IDs.length;
        //if no games, then build a game
        if(n == 0){
            initGame(n);
        }
        //else, determine placement in new vs existing game
        else{
            //if last - 1 has a spot, put me in that game, else create me a new game
            var checkThisGame = games.$child(IDs[n-1]);
            checkThisGame.$on('loaded',function(){
                if(checkThisGame.oIsAvailable == true){
                    checkThisGame.oIsAvailable = false;
                    checkThisGame.$save();
                    deferred.resolve(checkThisGame);
                }
                else{
                    initGame(n);
                }
            });
        }
    return deferred.promise;    
    });
}])
```

In my controller, I then use the resolved promise to fulfill my objectives:

```
app.controller ('BoardCtrl', function($scope,$timeout,GameCreator,$window) {
    GameCreator.then(function(returnedData){
        returnedData.$on('loaded',function(){
            $scope.game = returnedData;
            var piece;
            if(returnedData.oIsAvailable == true) {
                piece = 'x';
            }
            else {
                piece = 'o';
            }
            $scope.myPiece = {
                val:piece
            };
            $window.onbeforeunload = function (event) {
                //delete this game from the firebase I/O
                returnedData.$remove();
                return null;
            }
            //the rest of the tic tac toe game logic follows here,
            //with all proper calls to $scope.game.$save()
        });
    });
);
```

Since I do not completely know what I am doing, I will ask: did I do this right?  Is there some refactoring that could be done?  It works as expected but I thought I would ask for a review.

Answer (score 1):

I am not an angular expert, but this

```
var piece;
if(returnedData.oIsAvailable == true) {
    piece = 'x';
}
else {
    piece = 'o';
}
$scope.myPiece = {
    val:piece
};
```

could be

```
$scope.myPiece = {
    val: returnedData.oIsAvailable ? 'x' : 'o'
};
```

Also

- I know the firebase API calls the object returned by `new Firebase` a (root) reference. It still irks me since my brain keeps thinking what is `ref`?? I would probably go against the grain and call it `db`, but that could be because I am simply not familiar enough with the API
- `if(checkThisGame.oIsAvailable == true){` should be `if(checkThisGame.oIsAvailable){` or `if(checkThisGame.oIsAvailable === true){`
- the game is well documented
- JsHint.com finds a number of small things, you should use the site